# Email Not sent from salesforce, assignment rule

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

Hi I created an assignment rule to assign a case to the case queue when status=New , selected an email template so that it sends an email. But when I tested it, I did not receive any emails. The assignment rule is active and the email template is available for use.

Answer (score 0):

When creating Case, there is a option to select the checkbox '**Assign using active assignment rules**'.

We will be only able to get the email and case record assignment based upon the active assignment rule if we are selecting that option.

[image]